# How can I execute a SQL script when the linked server connects successfully?

Tags: sql, sql-server, linked-server

How to execute SQL script when the linked server connects success.

this script from other website.
but i didn't know how to insert query below the script when connection success.

```
----------------------------------------------
declare @srvrnvarchar(128),@retvalint;

set@srvr='MylinkedServerName';

begintry

exec @retval=sys.sp_testlinkedserver@srvr;

endtry

begincatch

set @retval=sign(@@error);

endcatch;

if@retval<> 0

raiserror('Unable to connect toserver. This operation will be tried later!',16, 2 );
-----------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking?

Comment: That SQL isn't valid either. `BEGIN`, `END`, TRY`, and `CATCH` are all separate keywords. There is no `ENDTRY` keyword.

Comment: how to create sql script use for below.

SSMS -> check linked server connection -> if connected linked -> run SQL query -end
if linked serverconnection  failure  --> quit process.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all
i find the answer.

```
    DECLARE @tryTimes INT, @linkedServerName nvarchar(128), @returnVal INT
SET @tryTimes=5
SET @linkedServerName='server1'

WHILE @tryTimes>0
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
        EXEC @returnVal = sys.sp_testlinkedserver @linkedServerName
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        SET @returnVal=SIGN(@@ERROR)
    END CATCH

    IF @returnVal=0
    BEGIN
        BREAK;
    END
    WAITFOR DELAY '00:02:00'
    SET @tryTimes=@tryTimes-1
END

IF @returnVal <> 0
BEGIN
    RAISERROR ('Cannot connect LinkedServer',16,2);
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT count(*) FROM [xxxx].[xxxx].[xxxx].[xxxxxx]
    PRINT 'run your query'
END
```

Answer (score 0):

An improved version of your retry logic.

- `sp_testlinkedserver` will throw if there is an exception, so just catch that.
- Rethrow thr original exception if it keeps failing.
- Put the actual query into a separate dynamic SQL batch, otherwise you may get errors right at the beginning when it tries to compile the whole batch.

```sql
DECLARE @tryTimes INT = 5, @linkedServerName sysname = 'server1';

WHILE @tryTimes > 0
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
        EXEC sys.sp_testlinkedserver @linkedServerName;
        BREAK;
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        SET @tryTimes -= 1;
        IF @tryTimes = 0
            THROW;
    END CATCH

    WAITFOR DELAY '00:02:00';
END;

EXEC sp_executesql N'
SELECT count(*)
FROM [xxxx].[xxxx].[xxxx].[xxxxxx];
';  -- add parameters as needed
```

I must say, the wisdom of doing this is suspect. If there is an error when connecting then it's unlikely that error will change within 2 seconds. It might be wiser to put this logic within your client application instead, and allow the user to decide what to do.